# java : How to assign custom values to char

Tags: java

```
 char c = formbean.getOptionType().value().charAt(0)
```

Hi , the above line either returns 'P' or 'C' .
So the value of char c would be either 'P' Or 'C' .

Now , my question is , instead of assigning 'P' Or 'C' values , i want to assign 0 or 1 respectively .

( For example if the value is 'P' , i need to assign it 0 and if the value is 'C' i need to assign it to 1 ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (formbean.getOptionType().value().charAt(0) == 'P')
    char c = 0;
else if (formbean.getOptionType().value().charAt(0) == 'C')
    char c = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'P' and 'C' are the only values returned, then something like this would do you...

```
char c = (formbean.getOptionType().value().charAt(0) == 'P')?'0':'1';
```

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you want, but you can assign integer values directly to `char` types, like so:

```
char c = (char) ((formbean.getOptionType().value().charAt(0) == 'P') ? 0 : 1);
```

But since this is not really intuitive and not as easy to read as it could be, it might be better practice to refactor it to a method:

```
private char getOptionTypeChar(char aChar) {
  if (aChar == 'P') {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

and then simply call it:

```
char c = getOptionTypeChar(formbean.getOptionType().value().charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends: What is the variable `c` representing and how will it be used?

If you want a 0 or a 1 then an `int` or `boolean` might be a better variable type to assign to. In any case the most obvious way to do what you're asking is to use an if/else statement. Here's an example assuming you want a 0 or 1 so you can make a decision (as I said it depends on what you intend to do with `c`):

```
char c = formbean.getOptionType().value().charAt(0);
boolean goLeft;

if (c == 'C') {
    goLeft = true;
} else if (c == 'P') {
    goLeft = false;
} else {
    // Handle error maybe
}

if (goLeft) {
    // Go left
} else {
    // Go right
}
```